# How can I separate and organize multiple Angular project build commands defined in a single package.json file?

Tags: node.js, angular, package.json

My Angular project is a monolithic application with more than 35 projects defined in the angular.json file. Consequently, the package.json file has over 245 different combinations of build commands. This has made the package.json file lengthy and difficult to manage. Here is a simplified example:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "project1": {},
        "project2": {},
        "project3": {},
        "project4": {},
        ...
        "project38": {}
    }
}
```

```
{
    "name": "myangular project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
         "build:project1:tenant1": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant1-dev --watch=true",
         "build:project1:tenant2": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant2-dev --watch=true",
         "build:project1:tenant3": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant3-dev --watch=true",
         
         "build:project1:tenant1-ci": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant1-ci",
         "build:project1:tenant2-ci": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant2-ci",
         "build:project1:tenant3-ci": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant3-ci",
         
         "build:project1:test": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant1 --watch=true",
         
         
         .........
         
         
         "build:project38:tenant1": "ng build --project=project38 -c=tenant1-dev --watch=true",
         "build:project38:tenant2": "ng build --project=project38 -c=tenant2-dev --watch=true",
         "build:project38:tenant3": "ng build --project=project38 -c=tenant3-dev --watch=true",
         
         "build:project38:tenant1-ci": "ng build --project=project38 -c=tenant1-ci",
         "build:project38:tenant2-ci": "ng build --project=project38 -c=tenant2-ci",
         "build:project38:tenant3-ci": "ng build --project=project38 -c=tenant3-ci",
         
         "build:project38:test": "ng build --project=project38 -c=tenant1 --watch=true",
         
    },
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        
    },
    "dependencies": {
        
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to organize these build commands into separate JSON files while keeping them accessible at the root package.json level when executing the commands. This will help simplify the package.json file and improve manageability.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Hi @VagnerlandioNunes Yes, Posted the answer below. if you think it can be improved. let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have split the package.json file into multiple smaller chunks and, during the build time, I merge them back into the package.json using a JavaScript script.

Here is a simplified example:

1. I have renamed the `package.json` file to `package.base.json` and removed the contents in the "scripts" section.  `package.base.json` file serves as the base for generating the actual package.json file

```
{
    "name": "myangular project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
         
    },
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        ...........
    },
    "dependencies": {
        ............
    }
}
```

2. Create a JSON file for each project, such as project1.json, project2.json,...., project38.json etc. Inside each JSON file, define the script commands specific to that project. (I kept all JSON files into Build-commands folder) For example:

```
{
    "build:project1:tenant1": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant1-dev --watch=true",
    "build:project1:tenant2": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant2-dev --watch=true",
    "build:project1:tenant3": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant3-dev --watch=true",
    
    "build:project1:tenant1-ci": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant1-ci",
    "build:project1:tenant2-ci": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant2-ci",
    "build:project1:tenant3-ci": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant3-ci",
    
    "build:project1:test": "ng build --project=project1 -c=tenant1 --watch=true"
}
```

3.Merge the `package.base.json` file and the build commands JSON files into the `package.json` file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Path to the folder containing JSON files
const currentPath = path.dirname(path.resolve(__filename));
const buildCommandsFolderPath = path.join(currentPath, 'build-commands');
const baseFilePath = path.join(currentPath, 'package.base.json');

// Dictionary to store the merged data
let mergedScripts = {};

// Iterate over each file in the folder
fs.readdirSync(buildCommandsFolderPath).forEach((filename) => {
  if (filename.endsWith('.json')) {
    const filePath = path.join(buildCommandsFolderPath, filename);
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));

    mergedScripts = { ...mergedScripts, ...data };
  }
});

// Read the base package.json file
const baseData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(baseFilePath));

// Merge the mergedScripts into the baseData's "scripts" object
baseData.scripts = { ...baseData.scripts, ...mergedScripts };

// Write the merged data to a new file
const outputFilePath = path.join(currentPath, 'package.json');

if (fs.existsSync(outputFilePath)) {
  fs.unlinkSync(outputFilePath);
}

fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, JSON.stringify(baseData, null, 4));


console.log('Merged JSON files successfully and created package.json');
```

4. Add package.json into .gitignore.
5. To add or modify dependencies and devDependencies, please make the necessary changes in the package.base.json file instead of pacakge.json.